# No Graphs available in Munin

Tags: munin

I have a problem using munin (on Ubuntu 10.05 LTS). No graphs are available. Instead, an image placeholder is shown.
I tried different settings, but it does not work.
I used http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/CgiHowto2 to set up CGI.
I also tried to find my error using http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/FAQ_no_graphs.

But still, no graph is available.
My settings and logs and telnet test: https://gist.github.com/Bjoernsen/bd7b9ab506ac55748292

Tell me, if I did not share all information

Answer (score 0):

Try to open "CGI image" directly and check the source. It must be an error messages from CGI.

Comment: I do not find an error message. If I call `http://localhost:5000/munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph/server/cooler.server/cpu-day.png`, I get a html (index) page with status 200, "Opened log file" (munin-cgi-html.log), `127.0.1.1:80 xxxx - - [30/Jul/2013:12:52:54 +0200] "GET /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph/server/cooler.server/cpu-day.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1228 "localhost:5000/munin/server/cooler.server/cpu.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"` (apache2/access.log).

Comment: What did you see when open /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph/server/cooler.server/cpu-day.png? Also check that munin generates RRD. Did they exists in data folder?

Comment: When I open the url, I see something like the index (html) page without any CSS. I know, it should be a .png. In the folder `/var/lib/munin/server/` are many .rrd files. But they are from this morning (5h old). I think they should be from now +- 5min. Maybe I had a working version during my tests :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, why no change in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/munin` effected the server.  There was a file link from '/etc/apache2/conf.d/' to the apache2.conf file in the munin folder. This file was always used and not my setting file.

Now, my settings are more or less the same like the settings found at http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/CgiHowto2

Answer (score 0):

Really helps to check the logs in `/var/log/munin`, and run munin in debug mode:

```
% munin-cron --debug > /tmp/munin-cron.debug 2>&1
```

The error I was getting was:

```
/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_mutex_trylock
```

Based on that error I suspected some kind of version mismatch.  After running `sudo yum update` (took a long time :-) munin started working.